# SQL Server: foreign key showing one to one relation instead of one to many

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, sql-server-2012-express

From some mystical reason I starter the database design with the inbuilt Database Diagrams GUI designer (Server Management Studio), actually I only did the first 2 tables (users and product) there rest were done using query commands.

It turns out that at the end there’s something I didn’t expect between:

- users (table)
- product(table)

I’ve created a foreign key column (“**users_id**”) in the “**product**” table pointing to the “**users**” table (column “**users_id**”).

Instead of having a one to many relation It seem to be a one to one relation?

Users table is referencing the product table and I don’t want this. 
What is the problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*edit: 4-sep-2014 10:48*

I've **droped** the **FK_product_TO_users** constraint and created a new one, but still the results are the same.

```
ALTER TABLE product
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_product_TO_users 
GO
ALTER TABLE product
ADD 
CONSTRAINT FK_product_TO_users 
FOREIGN KEY (users_id) 
REFERENCES users (users_id)
```

*edit: 4-sep-2014 12:51*

I've rebuilt the database, by using just Queries with no GUI help in the table design. The problem related to **FK_product_TO_users** was fixed, still I don't know why.

It comes out that after the resolution the same issue is present in two other tables with 2 FK relations.

Besides this, inputting data in those tables seems to work fine.
I'm wondering if this is just a bug of the GUI in the Database Diagram?

Comment: When you right click on the line connector in the diagram, you have the option to see the FK name and the related fields. It might show you what relationship is this.

Comment: @Caffé: yep I've done that check, but still I've got no clue. I've posted the image of the FK object property.

Answer (score 0):

This is really interesting one.
You can do one thing: just delete the key FK_product_to_users and rebuild the key.
You do NOT need to delete users_id from product table.

Comment: @masum7- I've just tried this option but it's not working. Check my edit, I've shown my t-sql query.

Comment: Can you please tell relationship of other associated tables, like categories? What other tables are related with the tables?